# Inverse limit of blow up

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, complex-geometry, blowup

Suppose $X_{0} = X$ is a complex space of dimension 2 with divisor $p_{0} \in X_{0}$. We can construct the blow-up, $X_{1}$ of $X$, which comes with a blow-down map $X_{1} \to X_{0}$. Suppose that there is a distinguished point $p_{1} \in X_{1}$. Then we can blow up again : $X_{2} \to X_{1}$. If this process continues indefinitely, we get a directed system of spaces:

$...\to X_{n} \to X_{n-1} \to ... \to X_{0}$.

In this case, it makes sense to consider the inverse limit $\lim_{\leftarrow} X_{n}$.

My question: Does such a space exist, and if so is there a nice description of it (or if possible a construction)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blowing up a point on a curve doesn't do anything, so I will assume you are talking about surfaces or higher dimensional varieties.

In that case, this inverse limit exists, but only as an inverse limit (although see edit). It's not a projective variety, for example because its cohomology group $H^2(X,\mathbf Z)$ is infinite dimensional. But people still work with this object! Some names for this (or related objects) are [Zariski-Riemann space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski%E2%80%93Riemann_space) and [bubble space](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=g9GLXmR9qg0C&pg=PA307&lpg=PA307&dq=bubble%20space%20algebraic%20geometry&source=bl&ots=9ysD3LKHZs&sig=nhnbxf-c0UqJcqUPtJ5GVmUdcyw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_WSjVemyK9TQ7Aa4vp_YBA&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=bubble%20space%20algebraic%20geometry&f=false).

I don't know what it means to "compute" this space.

**Edit:** According to Wikipedia, the Zariski--Riemann space is a locally ringed space. So that's a geometric category, containing the category of schemes, in which this inverse limit can be realised.